# d3.js donut chart - add drop shadow to the highlighted section

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my project, I am using d3.js donut chart to display some data. On click of each of the arc sections, it will be highlighted. The requirement is to add a drop shadow effect to the highlighted section when clicked, so it will highlighted much more. I am using stroke to create a shadow effect, but it is not looking like a shadow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> D3 Js Example </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js" ></script>
    <script>

        var lastSelected = "";
var firstSelected = "";

var width = 450
    height = 450
    margin = 40

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

var normalArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 30).innerRadius(radius - 70);
var biggerArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 80).innerRadius(radius - 10);

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12}

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"])

var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {return d.value; })
var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))

  
svg
  .selectAll('whatever')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', normalArc)
  .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
  .style("opacity", 0.7)
  .attr('d', function(d, index) {
        // If this is the first segment make it a wider arc
        if (index === 0) {
            firstSelected = this;
            return biggerArc(d);
        } else {
            return normalArc(d);
        }
    }).on("click", function(d) {
        if (firstSelected) {
            d3.select(firstSelected).attr("d", normalArc).style("stroke-width", "0px")
            firstSelected = false;
        }
        if (lastSelected) {
            d3.select(lastSelected).attr("d", normalArc).style("stroke-width", "0px")
        }
       d3.select(this).attr("d", biggerArc).style("stroke", "black").style("stroke-width", "10px")
        .style("stroke-opacity","0.08")
        .style('stroke-location',"outer")
        .style('paint-order','stroke')
        .style('stroke-linejoin',"round")

        lastSelected = this;
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What specific problem are you encountering when trying to implement your desired change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching i am able to find the answer. we need to create the filter for the drop shadow and append that to the svg and in which ever arc you want ,you just add the filter as an attribute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> D3 Js Example </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js" ></script>
    <script>

        var lastSelected = "";
var firstSelected = "";

var width = 450
    height = 450
    margin = 40

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

var normalArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 30).innerRadius(radius - 70);
var biggerArc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 80).innerRadius(radius - 10);

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

 /* For the drop shadow filter... */
  var defs = svg.append("defs");

  var filter = defs.append("filter")
      .attr("id", "dropshadow")

  filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
      .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
      .attr("stdDeviation", 4)
      .attr("result", "blur");
  filter.append("feOffset")
      .attr("in", "blur")
      .attr("dx", 2)
      .attr("dy", 2)
      .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

  var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

  feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
      .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
  feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
      .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

var data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12}

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"])

var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {return d.value; })
var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))

  
svg
  .selectAll('whatever')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', normalArc)
  .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
  .style("opacity", 0.7)
  .attr('d', function(d, index) {
        // If this is the first segment make it a wider arc
        if (index === 0) {
            firstSelected = this;
            return biggerArc(d);
        } else {
            return normalArc(d);
        }
    }).on("click", function(d) {
        if (firstSelected) {
            d3.select(firstSelected).attr("d", normalArc).attr("filter", "");
            firstSelected = false;
        }
        if (lastSelected) {
            d3.select(lastSelected).attr("d", normalArc).attr("filter", "");
        }
       d3.select(this).attr("d", biggerArc).attr("filter", "url(#dropshadow)");
        lastSelected = this;
    })
    
    if(firstSelected){
        d3.select(firstSelected).attr("filter", "url(#dropshadow)");
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```